# Podman push results in layer representation error

Tags: redhat, podman

Podman Push is resulting in following Error Message:

```
Error: Copying this image requires changing layer representation, which is not possible (image is signed or the destination specifies a digest)
```

Registry itself is working, push from another host with same image works (different version though). How to fix this? Already tried nuking podman including graphroot and runroot.

- OS: RHEL 8.4
- Podman Version: 3.2.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i understood correctly by now, skopeo (used to pull/push etc within podman) is the "problem". In my case i pulled a signed image from redhat and I tried pushing it to my gitlab (=docker) registry. Afaik the docker registry doesn't take care of the signature and skopeo refuses to drop the signature by default.

So the easy but dirty fix is to use `podman push --remove-signatures`